# How can I code in X++ to copy a Fiscal Year to all companies from a base company thats been set up?

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

We are running Dynamics AX2012 R2 CU7 and we coded:,

"copy a Fiscal Year to all companies from a base company that's already been set up",

feature for our source system which was Dynamics AX 2009. The structures in Dynamics AX 2012 R2, CU7 is so different that I don't know how to go about achieving the same functionality through X++ coding.

Original Code:

```
void clicked()
{
  ModulePeriodStat ledger, bank, cust, asset, invent, prod, proj, purch, sales, tax, vend ;
    PeriodEnd        period;
    LedgerPeriod     ledgerPeriod2;
    CompanyInfo      companyInfo;
    Dialog                  dlg;
    ;

    super();

    dlg = new Dialog("Confirm: ");
    dlg.addText("You will create these periods in all companies "+date2str(period,321,2,2,2,2,4));
    dlg.run();
    if ((dlg.closedOk()))
    {
    ttsbegin;

    while select crosscompany companyInfo
    {
    if (companyInfo.dataAreaId != 'ct11' && companyInfo.dataAreaId != 'ct13' && companyInfo.dataAreaId != 'md11' && companyInfo.dataAreaId != 'mf11')
    changecompany(companyInfo.dataAreaId)
    {
        ledgerPeriod2 = null;
    while select forUpdate ledgerPeriod     // where (ledgerPeriod.PeriodEnd == period)
    {
        ledger = ledgerPeriod.StatusLedger;
        bank = ledgerPeriod.StatusBank;
        cust = ledgerPeriod.StatusCust;
        asset = ledgerPeriod.StatusFixedAsset;
        invent = ledgerPeriod.StatusInvent;
        prod = ledgerPeriod.StatusProd;
        proj = ledgerPeriod.StatusProj;
        purch = ledgerPeriod.StatusPurch;
        sales = ledgerPeriod.StatusSalesOrder;
        tax = ledgerPeriod.StatusTax;
        vend = ledgerPeriod.StatusVend;
        period = ledgerPeriod.PeriodEnd;
        ledgerPeriod2.PeriodStart = ledgerPeriod.PeriodStart;
        ledgerPeriod2.PeriodCode = ledgerPeriod.PeriodCode;
        ledgerPeriod2.PeriodEnd = period;
        ledgerPeriod2.PeriodStatus = ledgerPeriod.PeriodStatus;
        ledgerPeriod2.Commentaries = ledgerPeriod.Commentaries;
        ledgerPeriod2.StatusLedger = ledger;
        ledgerPeriod2.StatusBank = bank;
        ledgerPeriod2.StatusCust = cust;
        ledgerperiod2.StatusFixedAsset = asset;
        ledgerPeriod2.StatusInvent = invent;
        ledgerPeriod2.StatusProd = prod;
        ledgerperiod2.StatusProj = proj;
        ledgerPeriod2.StatusPurch = purch;
        ledgerperiod2.StatusSalesOrder = sales;
        ledgerPeriod2.StatusTax = tax;
        ledgerperiod2.StatusVend = vend;
        try
        {
        ledgerperiod2.insert();
        }
        catch (Exception::DuplicateKeyException)
        {
            period = period;
            print('Problem encountered with company: '+companyinfo.dataAreaId);
        }
    }
    }
    }
    ttscommit;
    box::info('Periods Created Successfully');
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you describe what "that feature" consists of?

Comment: Please see the edit, the feature was in the question and not in the body, I have now isolated it clearly, by duplication , into the body as well. - thanks for your interest.

Comment: Note, that the base company is the only company containing the new fiscal year, until the code copies it to all the  others as well. This is a great time saver if your organization has 80 companies or more in them and they all work to the same fiscal year (and financial) year.

Comment: I saw the feature description in the question title, but I'm not sure what you mean by "Fiscal Year". Could you give the path to call the form to manage fiscal years in AX 2009 and 2012?
Another idea would be to check the data import/export framework for an entity for fiscal years to copy data from one company to another.

Comment: Paths are: In 2012 R2 CU7 -> General Ledger\Setup\Financial Calendars\New Accounting Year. In 2009 -> General Ledger\Setup\Periods\Create New Fiscal Year -> we added a button here to "<create fiscal year in all companies>" which will only execute if the <create New Fiscal Year> has been done for the current company.

Comment: post the original code

Comment: Original Code is now copied - please see post above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need such a functionality in AX 2012.

From the [white paper](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/search/DownloadResults.aspx?q=%22Dynamics%20AX%202012%22%20%22what%27s%20new%22) (page 735) linked by FH-Inway:

> In Microsoft Dynamics AX 2009, the LedgerPeriod table and form are used to create and maintain the 
>   fiscal periods for a company.
>
> Reason for deprecation:
>   Global organizations operate as different legal entities in different geographical areas. 
>   However, they share a lot of data, such as charts of accounts, currencies, exchange 
>   rates, and calendars. Defining this reference and master data once and sharing it 
>   across legal entities reduces the cost of maintaining such data across the 
>   organization. However, ledger periods, and the associated AssetCalendar tables, did 
>   not provide sufficient support for this scenario and have been replaced with more 
>   robust shared fiscal calendars.
>
> Replaced by another feature:
>   The feature is no longer available and has been replaced with shared fiscal 
>   calendars.

Setup your shared fiscal calendar in [General Ledger\Setup\Fiscal calendar](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us//library/hh242146.aspx#Create_a_fiscal_calendar_and_fiscal_year).

Then select that fiscal calendar in [Genreral Ledger\Setup\Ledger](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us//library/hh208447.aspx).

**Update 2:**

The closing of ledger periods is done in the [Ledger Calendar](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh242506.aspx).
The open/closed status of a period is stored in the table `LedgerFiscalCalendarPeriod`.
Although it is global, it is linked to the `Ledger` table of which there is one per company.

Thus you have no need for *any* customization regarding ledger periods.

Comment: How would you have different open and closed periods for different companies, even though they will be the same periods (start/ending dates)? IE a period is closed for one company but open for another.

Comment: You can't if using the same calendar. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa571842.aspx

Comment: So we do have to "copy" it then to create unique / unshared instances for every company or am I understanding you wrong?

Comment: Any ideas how I can go about coding such a the copy then?

Comment: None. Maybe it is better to code per company closing instead, if needed.

Comment: Please make a new Answer with that as a suggestion, I can the close this question - thanks a stack for your contribution here.

Comment: Answer updated. A new answer would not answer your question as stated.

Comment: Hi Jan, can you please elaborate on your edit above on the additional table and form needed to code for different closures per company.

Answer (score 2):

You could take a look at the [white papers](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/search/DownloadResults.aspx?q=%22Dynamics%20AX%202012%22%20%22what%27s%20new%22) that describe the changes from AX 2009 to 2012. At least in [New, Changed, and Deprecated Features for Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=7225)  you will find multiple references to changes regarding fiscal years. You can also check out [About fiscal calendars, fiscal years, and periods [AX 2012]](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/ce1bd504-30b6-4c0c-8104-09ed92fcf410%28AX.60%29.aspx) on TechNet which is linked in the white paper.

What I was able to get from skimming through the information is that the data in the tables for fiscal years is now available in all companies, so no need to copy fiscal years into other companies. It seems you can define in the ledger which fiscal year a legal entity/company should use.

Comment: That will take ages and most likely won't give me the answers.

Comment: I guess it will take you about an hour to skim through these four white papers and determine if the structural change that influences your feature is described there or not. If you cannot describe the feature that was implemented in AX 2009 in more detail, I'm not sure what kind of help you are expecting.

Comment: It takes seconds if you search "LedgerPeriod". The search feature is available in most PDF readers.